# How to convert a statement to snake-case?

Tags: python, snakecasing

I tried lots of things which didn't support all cases and I made this one which is mixed of all answers.

```
def to_snake(camel_input):
    camel_input = camel_input.replace('&', '_and_')
    camel_input = re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', '_', camel_input).lower()
    words = re.findall(r'[A-Z]?[a-z]+|[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]|\d|\W|$)|\d+', camel_input)
    return '_'.join(words)
```

Result for `'my p&l AndP&L aa_BB_dd (teSt) AndMy P&L andAlsoP&L andAlso p&l A B aA'`:

```
print(to_snake('my p&l AndP&L aa_BB_dd (teSt) AndMy P&L andAlsoP&L andAlso p&l A B aA'))
```

```
my_p_and_l_and_p_and_l_aa_b_b_dd_te_st_and_my_p_and_l_and_also_p_and_l_and_also_p_and_l_a_b_a_a
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? I think you wanted to answer your own question. There is an option to do that when you fill out the "Ask Question" form.

Comment: Or you could submit it to the community wiki.